# SQL Server Express 2008 Configure for Remote Access via url

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-express, remote-access

I have installed SQL Server 2008 Express Edition on my Server.
I am hosting my applications on the same server.

I can remote in to my server with a ip xx.xxx.xxx.xx username and password

I can run SSMS on my server and connect to database as

- server: (local)\SQLExpress
- authentication: SQLServer
- user: username
- pwd: Password

I want to be able to access this SQL Server instance remotely, what I have done is:

- Enabled SQL Browser
- Enabled TCP/IP
- Inbound Firewall enable fro SQLservr.exe
- Enabled Firewall for port 1433

From my local pc SSMS, when I try to connect to:

- server : xx.xxx.xxx.xx\SQLExpress
- Authentication : SQL Server
- Username: user
- password: pwd

I get network error, to check if server name is correct.

1. Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?
2. Also I want to access my server with **sql.mydomain.com** not with IP or machine name. How can I get this done?

#### update:

After doing all above I missed to restart **SQL Server Service**
Now I am able to access my SQL Server remotely 
with this url
xx.xxx.xxx.xx\SQLExpress

How can I create a alias like
**sql.mydomain.com**
where should i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this worked.

1. On Domain control point www.mydomain.com A record to ip xx.xxx.xxx.xx.
2. On my server install SQL Server with default instance (MSSQLServer)
3. Enable TCP/IP on Client Protocols
4. Add Port 1433 incoming Firewall
5. Add Inbound Firewall for SQLservr.exe

That's it Now I am able to connect to my sql server remotely with mydomain.com, username and password

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the "SQL Server Configuration Manager" that the TCP/IP protocol is enabled.
[image: Network Protocols]